# Mysql Order results if a certain condition is met

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables: posts and custom_fields.

A post can have multiple custom_fields.

**Posts table**: id | title
**Custom Fields table**: id | post_id | custom_key | custom_value

What I want is show all posts, but show first the featured ones which are the ones that have: "custom_key = 'featured' AND custom_value='1'".

Not every posts have the custom_key="featured".

How can I make a mysql query that lists in this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN customfields 
      ON post_id=posts.id AND custom_key='featured' 
ORDER BY custom_value=1 DESC, id DESC;
```

Comment: This should show all posts but featured will be listed first.

Comment: @shakti, the "featured" is part of the outer join condition.